# I am not able to run external library

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having a little difficulty. I believe it's because of my lack of knowledge. The fact is, i have a external library, to run with a external hardware. This library is of that hardware and run some events. I ain't able to understand how to run this events in my program. follow the code that i am trying to use.

```
//An example of an implemented proxcard callback is as follows:
 grabba.proxcard.registerCallback(proxcardCallbacks, onError);
 var proxcardTimeoutFunction = function() {
     alert('Proxcard timed out');
 };
 var proxcardCallbacks = {
 //Functions may also be declared inline as seen here.
 triggeredEvent: function() {
     alert('Proxcard triggered');
 },
 //These functions are optional and unimplemented functions will simply not be called.
 //stoppedEvent : function () {
 //alert('Proxcard scanning stopped');
 //},
 scannedEvent: function(proxcard) {
 //proxcard contains data fields
 //Convert the data to a base 16 hex string
 var hexString = ons.grabba.util.integerArrayToHexString(proxcard.data);
     alert('Proxcard scanned event\n Data: ' + hexString + '\n' + "Type: " + proxcard.type);
 },
 //You may create a function separately as seen with proxcardTimeoutFunction here.
 timeoutEvent: proxcardTimeoutFunction
 };
```

I need to scan with the RFID of that hardware. For more information's, follow the documentation of the library:

http://cordova.grabba.com/legacy/versions/v1.0.18/GrabbaProxcard.html

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, when i try to run the code, the system enter in it, but stop in the line where i call the library. How if it don't had understood what i want to do.

Comment: For example i trying to run the registerCallback(callback, onError) and the example with is put bellow, but i ain't able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is not working as is, you have to replace the "proxcardCallbacks" and "onError" parameters with your own functions.

Try this:

```
 <button onclick="grabba.proxcard.registerCallback({     //Functions may also be declared inline as seen here.
    triggeredEvent: function () {
        alert('Proxcard triggered');
    },
    //These functions are optional and unimplemented functions will simply not be called.
    //stoppedEvent : function () {
    //alert('Proxcard scanning stopped');
    //},
    scannedEvent: function (proxcard) {
        ////proxcard contains data fields
        ////Convert the data to a base 16 hex string
        try {
            //alert('data: ' + proxcard.data);
            var hexString = grabba.util.integerArrayToHexString(proxcard.data);
            alert('Proxcard scanned event\n Data: ' + hexString + '\n');
        } catch (err) {
            alert('catch error ' + err);
        }
    },
    timeoutEvent: function () {
        alert('Proxcard timed out');
    }
}, function (errorString) {
    alert('on error ' + errorString);
});">Scan</button>
```

PS: Notice that I removed the "ons." from the begging of the "integerArrayToHexString" function.